# Getting unique objects using LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a person class:

```
Public Class Person
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Id {get; set;}
}

Public EqualityOnPerson : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
public bool Equals(PersonData x, PersonData y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

I have a list of person objects with duplicate Ids in it:

```
Person.Name = "ABC"
Person.Id = "123"

Person.Name = "CBA"
Person.Id = "123"

Person.Name = "DEF"
Person.Id = "456"

Person.Name = "GHI"
Person.Id = "789"

Person.Name = "JKL"
Person.Id = "789"

Person.Name = "MNO"
Person.Id = "789"

Person.Name = "PQR"
Person.Id = "101"

Person.Name = "STU"
Person.Id = "102"
```

Using distinct will give

```
Person.Name = "CBA"
Person.Id = "123"

Person.Name = "DEF"
Person.Id = "456"

Person.Name = "GHI"
Person.Id = "789"

Person.Name = "PQR"
Person.Id = "101"

Person.Name = "STU"
Person.Id = "102"
```

How do I get this

```
Person.Name = "DEF"
Person.Id = "456"

Person.Name = "PQR"
Person.Id = "101"

Person.Name = "STU"
Person.Id = "102"
```

Only those person objects which are not duplicated.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the people using your equality comparer, then select people from groups with only one person in:

```
var unduplicatedPersons = persons
    .GroupBy(p => p, new EqualityOnPerson())
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

---

Here's a dedicated extension method which may have a slight performance edge if required (just for fun):

```
public IEnumerable<T> DistinctOnly<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                      IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    HashSet<T> all = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    HashSet<T> distinct = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    foreach (T t in source)
    {
        if (all.Add(t))
            distinct.Add(t);
        else
            distinct.Remove(t);
    }
    return distinct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = persons.Where(outer => 
     persons.Count(inner => inner.Id == outer.Id ) < 2)
```

This way you won't need an equality comparer.

Comment: It's not very efficient, though, and you could always use `GroupBy` with a selector to the ID if you wanted to avoid using an equality comparer.

Comment: @Rawling yes you're right about the efficiency, but this option is a bit clearer than grouping and counting the elements in the group, in my opinion. And performance won't be the issue if the initial list is not large(but this is just a speculation on my part).